# Algorithm to determine if a vertex is in any of the shortest paths

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

Given an undirected graph G = {E,V}, with positive edge costs. For all node combinations, is there a way do determine if a certain node v is not on any of the shortest paths that its not an endpoint?

My thought is that it could be done by performing a modified form of Dijkstra's Algorithm on each node except for v, where it would mark if a v was in the solution. But I'm not sure how to modify the algorithm to do this.

Comment: Between two specific nodes a an b, there might be multiple shortest paths, do you want at least 1 of these paths not have v in them? or all of them must not have v?

Comment: All of them must not have v

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `v` is the vertex and `a` and `b` are the starting and ending points relatively.

1. find shortest path length from `a` to `b`.
2. find shortest path length from `a` to `v` and `v` to `b`.
3. If sum of step 2 is equal to value of step 1, `v` is on a potential shortest path from `a` to `b`.

**PS**: The algorithm time complexity remains same as finding shortest path.

**Update**: Dijkstra starts from one node and propagate minimum distances from that to other nods. It do this until it reaches all nodes(`while Q is not empty`). If you are interested one specific node(end point) you can do this process in Dijkstra until you reach that point(i.e suppose `t` is target point, you do (minimum)distance propagation until `u` extracted from `Q`. On the other hand at this line `u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]` such that `u equals t` you can `return dist[u]`). Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for more detailed explanation about Dijkstra and good graphical illustrations.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Dijkstra's or does it require a different shortest path algorithm? Since according to what I've read Dijkstras only lets you specify a start node and you cant specify an end node.